# Using ReactDOM.render inside an event handler to avoid rendering expensive components

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, material-design

I have a React app with a list of tasks which each have due dates. I want the user to be able to click the due date to pop up a datepicker to select a new one.

I am using the material UI library http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

I could simply render a datepicker on each task in the list but it seems like it might cause performance problems on a long list to render such a complex component on each item. I would prefer to just display the due date and only render the datepicker when the user clicks to change the due date.

Here is the solution I have come up with:

```
TaskFooter = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        task: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    },
    onDateChanged(e, newDate){
        // handle data update
    },
    showDatePicker(){
        let dp = ReactDOM.render(
            <MUI.DatePicker autoOk={true} textFieldStyle={{display: 'none'}} onChange={this.onDateChanged} />,
            this.refs.datePickerContainer
        );
        dp.openDialog();
    },
    render() {

        return (
                <div onClick={this.showDatePicker}>
                    <MUI.Libs.SvgIcons.ActionEvent />
                    {this.props.task.duedate}
                    <div ref="datePickerContainer"></div>
                </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This seems to work, but I want to know if this pattern is the "correct" way to do this. Is there a better way to dynamically render potentially expensive react components in response to an event?

Edit:
I have found another way to do this which seems more "react" but I am not sure if it is entirely correct.

```
TaskFooter = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        task: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    },
    getInitialState(){
        return {
            showDatePicker: false
        }
    },
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        if(this.state.showDatePicker && !prevState.showDatePicker){
            this.refs.datePicker.openDialog();
        }
    },
    onDateChanged(e, newDate){
        console.log('new date', newDate);
        this.setState({
            showDatePicker: false
        });
    },
    showDatePicker(){
        this.setState({
            showDatePicker: true
        });
    },
    render() {

        return (
                <div onClick={this.showDatePicker}>
                    <MUI.Libs.SvgIcons.ActionEvent />
                    {this.props.task.duedate}
                    { this.state.showDatePicker ?
                        <MUI.DatePicker autoOk={true} textFieldStyle={{display: 'none'}} onChange={this.onDateChanged} ref="datePicker" />
                    : ''}
                </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This correctly shows and hides the datepicker, but when setting the closed state I get the following warning in my console:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the DatePickerDialog component.
```

Despite this warning it seem the state is correctly set on my component. Should I ignore this warning? Is my new pattern correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only use `ReactDOM.render()` when mounting your React app. It should never be used within a React component itself.

Familiarise yourself with how *state* works. I suggest the following:

```
TaskFooter = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        task: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            displayDatePicker: false
        };
    }
    onDateChanged(e, newDate) {
        // handle data update
    },
    showDatePicker() {
        this.setState({
            displayDatePicker: false
        });
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        // this is a little bit hacky,
        // ideally there would be a prop for DatePicker to instruct it to already be open
        if (this.state.displayDatePicker && !prevState.displayDatePicker) {
            this.refs.dp.openDialog();
        }
    },
    render() {

        return (
            <div onClick={this.showDatePicker}>
                <MUI.Libs.SvgIcons.ActionEvent />
                {this.props.task.duedate}
                {this.state.displayDatePicker ? (
                    <MUI.DatePicker
                        ref="dp"
                        autoOk={true}
                        textFieldStyle={{display: 'none'}}
                        onChange={this.onDateChanged}
                    />
                ) : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This achieves the same thing in a cleaner fashion. The state variable `displayDatePicker` determines whether or not the datepicker shows. I've also used `componentDidUpdate()` to detect when the datepicker has just been activated.

One further thing however. I think you should question your assumption that displaying the datepicker by default would necessarily create performance problems. Do you know that to be the case? I fear you might be trading an increase in code complexity for a trivial performance boost.

Comment: I came to the same solution just as you posted. Thanks! I am still getting a warning in my console however. Please see my edit above.

Comment: When you set `showDatePicker` to false, you're removing the DatePicker from the DOM. My guess is at the same time you're doing this, the DatePicker is trying to change its own state in order to close the dialog. Hence the warning about changing the state of an unmounted component. Again I reiterate the question I posed in the my final paragraph above. Is it really necessary to duplicate the show/hide behaviour that is already built into the DatePicker component?

Comment: With some informal testing it seems to be ~30% slower when rendering a list of 25 items if I include the date picker in each one. Looking at the source of the component [here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/src/date-picker) it seems that the date picker renders quite a lot of components which are not shown until user interaction. I don't think this would be an issue except in a case like mine where I want to have a datepicker in each element of an arbitrarily sized list.